# defining div with when you are using a padding left to let place to another div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm looking for a CSS trick to fix ie8.

In the sample, i put a code to make two distinct column 'content' and 'menu'.

My problem on ie8 is that i have to change margin-left of content to 140px. < (If i don't do this, i don't get a correct margin on ie and content is on menu.)

But the div width doesn't change and that make a scrool bar on y axes that i don't want.

On others browsers, that make the job without specife the width and auto-width alone.

HTML :

```
<div class="menu">
   Menu
</div>

<div class="content">
   Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
   width: 110px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 60px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
.content {
    margin-left:110px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Any idea? Thanks!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9Gj/)

Comment: Its not too clear what you want / are experiencing, can you elaborate?

Comment: Try to put a width and float:right insteead of margin-left. But man, IE8 seriously ?? (5 years old)

Comment: @xABE I don't understand the question. Do you want to get rid of  `margin-left`?

Comment: u can add overflow-y:hidden; but i tested the codes in ie11 with developer tools in ie8 mode and dont see any scroolbar.

Comment: Seem that the div go out of browser in ie8.

Comment: @xABE not too sure what you're talking about, I don't get neither horizontal nor vertical scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

Here my fix for ie8

```
.l-content {    
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't even make sense it's completely different from any of the code you've provided in your question

Comment: But working fine. And whitout any help, i can only try to access a working way with my basics CSS skill.